# Edit Web Config file and apply changes

Tags: c#, windows, dictionary

Am doing a windows application in c#,  where i read web.config files inside a folder and load the appsettings where users can edit them and apply changes.

I store the settings 'key' and 'value'  in a dictionary and the effected values in a separate dictionary . It works well, but it takes lot of time to apply the changes.

How can i speed it up?

here is my code

```
public List<AppSettings> OldAppSetting;
public List<AppSettings> NewAppSetting;


        foreach (var oldSetList in OldAppSetting)
        {
            Document = Document = XDocument.Load(@oldSetList.FilePathProp);
            var appSetting = Document.Descendants("add").Select(add => new
            {
                Key = add.Attribute("key"),
                Value = add.Attribute("value")
            }).ToArray();

            foreach (var oldSet in appSetting)
            {
                foreach (var newSet in NewAppSetting)
                {
                    if (oldSet.Key != null)
                    {
                        if (oldSet.Key.Value == newSet.AppKey)
                        {
                            oldSet.Value.Value = newSet.AppValue;
                        }
                    }
                    Document.Save(@oldSetList.FilePathProp);
                }
            }

        }
```

here is the Appsettings class

```
 public class AppSettings
    {
        public string AppKey { get; set; }
        public string AppValue { get; set; }
        public string FilePathProp{ get; set; }



    }
```

Comment: What is your `Document.Save(@oldSetList.FilePathProp)`? WHat are the types of `appSetting` and `NewAppSetting`? Why do you use a keyword escaping for `oldSetList`?

Comment: What is an `appSetting` and a `NewAppSetting`?

Comment: saving the changes as a document

Comment: @Ic appSettings is the old appsettings in 1 web config file and newappsettings conatains the changes what they have made.

Comment: @Sajeetharan We need the type of those variables. `Dictionary<string, string>`? `XmlDocument`?

Comment: <>f__AnonymousType0<System.Xml.Linq.XAttribute,System.Xml.Linq.XAttribute>

Comment: Edit your question and show the declarations for `appSetting` and `NewAppSetting`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your primary speed concern is that you're saving the document after checking every item. Seems like you could change your code to reduce the number of times you call save. For example:

```
    foreach (var oldSetList in OldAppSetting)
    {
        Document = Document = XDocument.Load(@oldSetList.FilePathProp);
        var appSetting = Document.Descendants("add").Select(add => new
        {
            Key = add.Attribute("key"),
            Value = add.Attribute("value")
        }).ToArray();

        foreach (var oldSet in appSetting)
        {
            foreach (var newSet in NewAppSetting)
            {
                if (oldSet.Key != null)
                {
                    if (oldSet.Key.Value == newSet.AppKey)
                    {
                        oldSet.Value.Value = newSet.AppValue;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        Document.Save(@oldSetList.FilePathProp);
    }
```

Also, you could use a `Dictionary<string, AppSetting>` rather than an array for your `appSetting`. That would speed things up quite a bit if the number of items is large. It would take some restructuring of your code. I don't know what all of your types are, so I can't give you the exact code, but it would look something like this:

```
var appSetting = Document.Descendants("add")
    .ToDictionary(add => add.Attribute("key"));
foreach (var newSet in NewAppSetting)
{
    if (appSetting.ContainsKey(newSet.AppKey))
    {
        var oldSet = appSetting[newSet.AppKey];
        oldSet.Value.Value = newSet.AppValue;
    }
}
```

Your code is a little bit confusing, but I think that's right. The idea here is to build a dictionary of the old values so that we can look them up directly when scanning the new values. It turns your O(n^2) algorithm into an O(n) algorithm, which will make a difference if there are a lot of settings. Plus, the code is smaller and easier to follow.

Answer (score 1):

Put the

```
Document.Save(@oldSetList.FilePathProp);
```

Outside the loop!